# Paypal Classic API Test Credentials

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to test a Paypal Classic API integration and am having issues finding my Test Credentials.

Current error returned is: Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.

This makes sense as I'm using the Sandbox AppId and Live credentials for the account (which I know where to get obviously).

I've found this page: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_credentials/
which tells me where to go to get test credentials but I can't find the place it's talking about.

Logging in with the business account doesn't have the sections displayed in the graphic. Am I supposed to be logging in with a different account?

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to https://developer.paypal.com and log in (by clicking on the **Log In** button in the upper-right corner).  Use the email address and password from your live PayPal account to log in.
- Click **Dashboard**.
- Under **Sandbox**, click **Accounts**.
- There should be a facilitator account there (e.g., youremail-facilitator@yourdomain.com).  You can either use that account for the following steps, or you can click on **Create Account** and create a new account to use for the following steps.
- Click on the email address of the account.
- You'll see two links appear underneath the email address: **Profile** and **Notifications**.  Click on **Profile**.
- Click the **API Credentials** tab.